# Heroku push error: couldn't find file 'underscore'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, gmaps4rails

When I run `git push heroku master` I get the following error:

```
couldnt find file 'underscore'
   (in /tmp/build_f0c66118-074b-4228-82a2-374934addad5/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:19)
```

underscore.js was added as part of the [Gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) gem. It was put at vendor/assets/javascripts/underscore.js as shown in the video documentation of the gem.

`//= require underscore` is in my assets pipeline

Using "Production Version" of [underscore](http://underscorejs.org)
I've not worked in vendor/assets before so not sure if I missed some step that goes along with putting .js files in there.

Comment: The author is on here http://stackoverflow.com/users/350087/apneadiving - You should update your Q with a tag / ref to `Gmaps4rails`

Comment: No typo in the filename? Which version of rails? Mive the file wherever you want if this is the only thing slowing you down

Comment: @apneadiving No typo, using rails 4.0.0, ruby 2.0.0p247. I had tried moving it into app/assets/javascripts folder but still got the same error.

Comment: Ok and did you commit and pushed underscore.js? This is not a gmaps4rails related issue, its a generic asset pipeline question

Comment: Did you solve this problem @Jadam

Comment: @SarpKaya I did not ever get this solved unfortunately.